# Objective-C SpriteKit – How to make circle of buttons

Tags: ios, objective-c, button, sprite-kit, geometry

I have some code in a project already, but I'd like to change it up a bit. Currently, my code creates an empty node called `_buttonLayer` and then create some buttons to add to it. My buttons start from the top-left corner of the `_buttonLayer` and then get added all the way to the bottom-right corner.

```
// Set up button layer.
_buttonLayer = [SKNode node];
_buttonLayer.position = CGPointMake(_centerOfScreen.x - (_buttonSize.width * 1.5) - 5.0,
                                    self.size.height - ((self.size.height * 0.375) + (_buttonSize.height) - 50.0) + 5.0);
[self addChild:_buttonLayer];


// Set up button array.
_buttonArray = [NSMutableArray array];


// Add some buttons.
for (char row = 0; row < 4; row++) {
    for (char col = 0; col < 4; col++) {

        // Buttons.
        SKSpriteNode *button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"LightGreyButton"];
        button.name = @"LightGreyButton"; // Initially set it to grey, because they all start off that way.
        button.size = _buttonSize;
        button.position = CGPointMake(2.0 + ((button.size.width + 3.0) * col),
                                      -(2.0 + ((button.size.height + 3.0) * row)));
        [_buttonLayer addChild:button];
        [_buttonArray addObject:button];

    }
}
```

So what I need to do now is create the buttons in a circle – instead of in a square. I'd like to somehow add the buttons into an outline of a circle, and then take the whole `_buttonLayer` and rotate it. Of course, the way I have it right now, it rotates on the top-left corner of the square. I want the middle of the circle to rotate.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `for` loop to this:

```
int numberOfButtons = 4; // The number of buttons you want.
int radiusOfCircle = button.size.width*4; // The radius of the circle that will contain those buttons.

for (int i = 0; i < numberOfButtons; i++) {

    // Buttons.
    SKSpriteNode *button = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"LightGreyButton"];
    button.name = @"LightGreyButton"; // Initially set it to grey, because they all start off that way.
    button.size = _buttonSize;
    CGFloat angle = 2*M_PI/numberOfButtons * i;
    button.position = CGPointMake(radiusOfCircle*cos(angle),radiusOfCircle*sin(angle));
    [_buttonLayer addChild:button];
    [_buttonArray addObject:button];
}
```

Also, as Darvydas suggested, if you want to rotate a `sprite` around a certain `CGPoint centerOfRotation`, set `sprite.anchorPoint = centerOfRotation;`.

Keep in mind that I have written this without testing (and I'm more used now to Swift than Objective-C). But I think it should work... Did it? :)

Comment: Thank you, @RoberRM! This should definitely help me out. I will try it and let you know if it works.

Comment: It seems it did help you. I'm glad. :)  Good luck on your game!

Answer (score 0):

To make nodes round instead of `SKSpriteNode` you should use `SKShapeNode`

```
SKShapeNode* button = [SKShapeNode node];
[button setPath:CGPathCreateWithRoundedRect(CGRectMake(-50, -50, 100, 100), 50, 50, nil)];
```

Make button fill invisible

```
    button.fillColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

Change outline width

```
    button.lineWidth = 100
```

More information here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKShapeNode_Ref/index.html

To rotate your node around center set `anchorPoint` to your node center

Comment: thank you for your response, but you misunderstood my question. I don't need to crate an outline of a circle. I need to add a bunch of sprites on a circle path, instead of the square path that the given code in my question creates.

Comment: @ChristianKRider ups, have you checked RobertRM answer? I think he gave you good answer :)